# Including only selected urls in django

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I have a third party app with the following url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^webhook/(?P<token>[-_:a-zA-Z0-9]+)', TelegramView.as_view(), name='webhook'),
    url(r'^bots', BotViewSet, name='api'),
]
```

Now I want to include only the second url (with namespace 'api') because I have overridden the first one in my own app (It will be handled by my own views). How do I use include so that it only includes the second url?

Comment: Have you tried, adding the `BotViewSet` into your urls directly (without include)? Just like `url(r'^bots', BotViewSet, name='api')` and importing the `BotViewSet` into your own `url.py`?

Comment: I can do that, but what of a case where I don't know all the contents of the third party app's urls? or they are too long? It will not be so good to add the urls manually in my app. Again the app can decide to add other urls after an update. It means I have to always check what they have added and add it to mine. Not a scalable solution

Comment: Okay, good point. Then why not but your custom `url(r'^webhook/(?P<token>[-_:a-zA-Z0-9]+)', TelegramView.as_view(), name='webhook')` before the include. Django walks through your patterns and uses the first one that matches your url. So if your custom endpoint is met before your third party one, that one will be used.

Comment: @Remi, I was thinking about that but I was thinking, django would override the already existing one if a new one is given. let me try it out